# PostgreSQL 15: ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown || double precision

Tags: postgresql, cast

we are using a PostgreSQL version 15 and have added 13 conversions from this blog entry:
http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html

However, only now we have the problem when we want to join a string e.g. with a number:

```
SELECT 'Test: '||123.45 FROM TEST
```

The SQL returns the error here:

> ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown || integer

If we remove the conversion "double percision --> text", the SQL works. However, we need the conversions elsewhere.
We actually want to avoid using `CAST()`, `::VARCHAR` or `::TEXT`, as this affects a large number of queries.

Does anyone have any ideas on how we can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. change your statement to make clear that the first argument is a `text`:

   ```
   SELECT 'Test: '::text || 123.45
   ```
2. drop the extra type casts and fix your SQL statements

I think that the second option is the better one.

Comment: Option 2 cannot be implemented because the queries are used in an environment that includes several database types.

Comment: Pshaw. Don't tell me that other databases don't understand queries that use data types correctly. no database insists on you concatenating strings with numbers...

Comment: Other database allow implicit cast. We are just introducing PostgreSQL and have now encountered the problem mentioned above.

Comment: I understand. But that doesn't rule out the second option. Being unambiguous about data types can actually prevent undesired behavior of the query. I can understand that the pain to fix all your SQL statements is great, but it might be the better option in the long run.